# Parse markup fragment into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to parse a fragment of XML using Javascript and put the results in an array. I live in the PHP world, and because of the requirements, this has to be in Javascript, so stumbling a bit on a solution. I need the 'name' and 'value' values of all 'variable' attributes inside the 'variables' element. Using the myVars variable below, which in reality has a lot more markup, it would return an associative array like this:

```
array={fname:'Gene',lname:'Simmons'};
```

Here's the markup.

```
var myVars = '<variables><variable name="fname" type="string" value="Gene" resume="true"/><variable name="lname" type="string" value="Simmons" resume="true"/><variable name="LastSlideViewed" type="string" value="_player.3093j3" resume="true"/></variables><actiongroups><actiongroup id="ActGrpOnSubmitButtonClick"><actions><trigger_submit_slide/></actions></actiongroup><actiongroups>';
```

In a perfect world, I would be able to exclude certain 'variable' elements that had a certain 'name' value. For example, exclude all elements where their 'name' value is in an 'exclude' array, such as:

```
var exclude = ["LastSlideViewed", "FirstSlideViewed"];
```

So the reason why the array above only has the fname and lname keys is because we're only getting 'variable' elements from the 'variables' element and excluding those elements with 'name' values found in the exclude array, and we're also ignoring anything outside the 'variables' element, such as the 'actiongroups' element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I may be getting close:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(myVars,"text/xml");

x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('variable');
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    myAssociativeArr.push({name: x[i].getAttribute('name'), value: x[i].getAttribute('value')});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are pretty close. JavaScript doesn't use the term "associative array", but an object in JavaScript is a lot like what you would call an associative array.

I've modified your code to use an object, and added an `if` statement to omit the excluded items. This works:

```js
var myVars = '<variables><variable name="fname" type="string" value="Gene" resume="true"/><variable name="lname" type="string" value="Simmons" resume="true"/><variable name="LastSlideViewed" type="string" value="_player.3093j3" resume="true"/></variables><actiongroups><actiongroup id="ActGrpOnSubmitButtonClick"><actions><trigger_submit_slide/></actions></actiongroup><actiongroups>';

var exclude = ["LastSlideViewed", "FirstSlideViewed"];

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(myVars, "text/xml");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('variable');
var myAssociativeArr = {};
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var name = x[i].getAttribute('name');
  if (exclude.indexOf(name) === -1) {
    myAssociativeArr[name] = x[i].getAttribute('value');
  }
}

console.log(myAssociativeArr);
```

If you did actually want to use an array of objects like you were constructing in your code, you can just revert that part to the way you had it:

```js
var myVars = '<variables><variable name="fname" type="string" value="Gene" resume="true"/><variable name="lname" type="string" value="Simmons" resume="true"/><variable name="LastSlideViewed" type="string" value="_player.3093j3" resume="true"/></variables><actiongroups><actiongroup id="ActGrpOnSubmitButtonClick"><actions><trigger_submit_slide/></actions></actiongroup><actiongroups>';

var exclude = ["LastSlideViewed", "FirstSlideViewed"];

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(myVars, "text/xml");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('variable');
var myAssociativeArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var name = x[i].getAttribute('name');
  if (exclude.indexOf(name) === -1) {
    myAssociativeArr.push({name: name, value: x[i].getAttribute('value')});
  }
}

console.log(myAssociativeArr);
```